# Not too hot, not too cold. Just right

Tags: sentence-meaning

According to the popular story of Goldilocks and the Three Bears, in which the young girl Goldilocks enters the bears' house during their absence, tastes their bowls of porridge, and finds one too hot, another too cold, but the last one just right, there is a proverbial well-know sentence:

> - Not too hot, not too cold. Just right

What does this sentence exactly mean? Do it mean, you shouldn't go to extreams and it would be better to keem the middle ground or it has another connotation?

Comment: It means exactly what is says. It's a literal statement.

Answer (score 3):

The text is not "proverbial". It merely states that the temperature of the porridge was, in the opinion of Goldilocks, neither too hot nor too cold. It has no extra, hidden, or implied meaning about "avoiding extremes".